# Grouping by column and concatenating another column

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to group table by the id column and then display the values of another column in a concatenated list. This is the original table:

[Original Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGNqy.png)

And this is the desired outcome:

[Desired Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1il6.png)

Is there any way to do this in Power Bi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a calculated Table using this:

```
Table2 = SUMMARIZE (
    'Table',
    'Table'[Column1],
    "All", CONCATENATEX ( VALUES ( 'Table'[Column2] ), 'Table'[Column2], "," )
)
```